# R "rast" unknown extent patternize package

Tags: r, raster, extent

I'm playing around with the R package "patternize" in an attempt to compare flower colours. The images are jpg format (each image a single flower with a white background)).

When loading the images a warning error is generated:

“[rast] unknown extent”

.. following this no further downstream code will work (alignment /or image registration).

Therefore I assume it's necessary to first delineate the jpg boundaries "extents" in order to overlay? Would anyone please help on what would be the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should be fixed now (https://github.com/StevenVB12/patternize). It seems that the raster package was not assigning a coordinate system anymore to the images.

Let me know if it fails again!

Best,

Steven